# Jetpack compose "Text" function deprecated (1.0.0-alpha09)

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose

*(config:  compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha09'    kotlin_version = "1.4.21")*

The Jetpack Composable function "Text" is deprecated

```
Text( // <===== Strikethrough in Android Studio
    text = "Anna"
)
```

but I can't figure out how to replace it. The doc says to replace by ... Text

```
@Deprecated(
    message = "Use androidx.compose.material.Text for a high level Text component that " +
        "consumes theming information, or androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicText for a basic " +
        "unopinionated component that does not have default theming",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith(
        "Text(text, modifier, color, fontSize, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontFamily, " +
            "letterSpacing, textDecoration, textAlign, lineHeight, overflow, softWrap, maxLines, " +
            "onTextLayout, style)",
        "androidx.compose.material.Text"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `androidx.compose.foundation.Text` import to

```
import androidx.compose.material.Text
```

to use the non-deprecated Material version of `Text`, which is the drop in replacement for what `Text` did in previous alphas.

Comment: Thanks.  The same applies to androidx.compose.material.Icon